# Enumeration in Repository Pattern c#

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

How can I read from my database an int attribute that in my system is an Enumeration type attribute in the Repository Pattern, C #.

I made a class:

```
public class Status : Enumeration
{
    public static readonly Status Active = new Status(0, "Active");
    public static readonly Status Inactive = new Status(1, "Inactive");
    public static readonly Status Removed = new Status(2, "Removed");

    public Status()
    {
    }

    private Status(int value, string displayName)
        : base(value, displayName)
    {
    }
}
```

So in the Bank class I put a Status attribute;

At the time of reading from the bank where my Bank class is and a table with an attribute Status type int, plus the attribute gets null.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you use EntityFramework or just plain ADO.net?

Comment: ADO.net with DapperRepository

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this site requires that you post your questions in *English* only. Please translate this yourself; someone else translating for you will not help you understand comments and answers, or respond to feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would introduce a static method to convert integers to "enum" in your class, for example

```
    public class Status : Enumeration
    {
       //YOUR CODE

      public static Status FromInteger(int value){
        switch(value){
          case 0: 
            return Active;
          case 1: 
            return Inactive;
          case 2: 
            return Removed;
          default: 
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
      }
    }
```

I have not dealt with DapperRepository. But quick look at `ClassMapper<T>` reveals that you may leverage custom conversion using AutoMap method. However, I did not find neither documentation nor example.
Therefore, I can propose only a universal solution.

```
    public class Bank {

       //Standard fields that are mapped to a table in database 

       public Status StatusEnum {
         get {
            Status.FromInteger(StatusId); //StatusId is a property mapped to table's field
         }

         set {
            //TODO Handle null value
            StatusId = value.Value;
         }
       }
    }
```

NOTE:

- I assume that property `StatusId` is a field mapped to the table's field that contains status value.
- This code has obvious problem - StatusId allows values that are out of enum range. You will have to do some additional validation to maintain data consistency.

Comment: Thank you very much